# Background Worker won't report progress

Tags: c#, loops, backgroundworker

I have a Backrgound Worker which won't report progress. I need to get an exact value, not a percentage. I'm not sure how to code the progress changed event. I have set the WorkReportsProgress property to true. I'm still relatively new to C# so excuse my poor knowledge.

```
 private void BKGWork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
           //do work
           worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
 private void BKGWork_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
      //not sure how to get the exact value of i and compare it to see which loop the background worker is in.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `worker.ReportProgress(0,i);` to pass your explicit value as a user state parameter. Use can access this in `e.UserState` casting it to an int

Comment: Tried this method, but still not getting any result. Console is completely blank.

Comment: Have you called `RunWorkerAsync` to start the background worker? And are you sure your event handler is subscribed.

Comment: I figure it out, I hadn't declared the ProgressChanged event. Your method works.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you pass to `ReportProgress` as first parameter is the value that you receive in `e.ProgressPercentage`, the BackgroundWorker class cannot calculate a 'Percentage' for you. If you need a more complex data (an instance of a class for example you could use the second optional argument of ReportProgress and retrieve it in the UserState parameter

```
private void BKGWork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
       //do work
       worker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
private void BKGWork_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{  
    // This is the value of the variable i passed above
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

According to you comment below it seems that you haven't correctly setup the event handler. This is easy to discover if you can use a debugger. Put a breakpoint (F9) in the line inside the ProgressChanged event and run the program (F5). If the breakpoint is not hit then check if you have correctly set the Event Handler in the designer or in code. Otherwise if the breakpoint is hit then look at the Visual Studio's output window (At runtime, in a NON console application, the Console output is redirected to the Output window of Visual Studio)

Comment: I'm getting nothing on the console. Completely blank

Comment: If you can use a debugger then put a breakpoint in the line inside the ProgressChanged event and run the program. If the breakpoint is not hit then check if you have correctly set the Event Handler in the designer or in code. Otherwise if the breakpoint is hit then you are not looking at the output window (at runtime, in a NON console application, the Console output is redirected to the Output window of Visual Studio)

Comment: I hadn't declared the event handler for the ProgressChanged event. Stupid me. Thanks for the heads up tho :)